# Links On folders

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have an issue on my company: I see this options(customized) my view[image] but my other team mate does not have link option as you can see. [image]

What i am doing wrong? This can be permissions, if so where?

Thanks

Comment: In the future, use the select functionality of your image editor and then use the bucket fill to color block an area. Make sure to completely block all portions desired exactly the same. I can kind of view what you are trying to hide by looking and comparing both images.

Answer (score 1):

How do you add the customized "Link" option (customized)?

Go to the library->Library Settings->Advanced Settings->Choose "Yes" for Allow management of content types.

In the library settings add a document content type.

This does remove the "Link" Options.

Go to the library->Library Settings->Advanced Settings->Choose "No" for Allow management of content types.

Then we can see the "Link" Options.

Comment: Much clearer and concise than my answer. +1

Comment: I do not add "Link" option here. It appears on my side.